# How can I setup simulations of an equation with constraints?

Tags: r

I have data on 4 items for 100 people. It is setup as follows:

```
#Initial Data (Items) and Weights. Shares is the final results.
items <- data.frame(Names = c("Sarah", "John", "Tom"), Phones = c(1,2,1), Cars = c(2,1,1), Boxes = c(9,14,12), Cats = c(1,2,3))
weights <- c(.5,.3,.15,.05,.95)
shares <- data.frame(Names = items[,1], Shares = 0, Rank = 0)
#Testing Weights and Calculating Rank
shares[,2] <- round((weights[1]*items[,2] + weights[2]*items[,3] + weights[3]*items[,4]+weights[4]*items[,5])^weights[5],3)
shares[,3] <- order(shares[,2], decreasing=T)
```

My goal is to run simulations for different weights under the following constraints:

The first weight (Phones) weights[1] >= .5

The 2nd weight (Cars)    .25 <= weights[2] <= .35

The 3rd weight (Boxes) weights[3] <= .15

The 4th weight (Cats) weights[4] = .05

Sum(weights[1:4]) = 1

weights[5] >= .95

To simulate different weights test steps of 0.01, i.e. one scenario weights <- c(.51,.3,.14,.05,.95) and these would change to test all possible values under the constraints.

I want to run simulations under these scenarios, my step could be 0.01, and track how an individual does in terms of their rank, i.e. if I care about Tom I want to follow his rank across different simulations. Rank is what matters. I can organize the data when I get it but how can I setup the simulations under this scenario?

Comment: "my step could be 0.01": what step?  `Rank=0` is the only reference to rank in your code.  Why do you need to "track rank" if it never changes?  Please provide details and clarity.

Comment: @Limey I added more context. The step is how the weights would change, that is what I am testing. Rank changes based on the equation and are recalculated on the final line of the code, it does change.